# Scrapy Webcrawler - How to filter out crawled content which is in a specific language?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, nltk

I am a python / scrapy newb - so please don't be to harsh on me :-).

I did build the following scrapy spider which crawls through some sites and extracts the crawled content (consisting of three different categories of data) and puts it into a list of dictionaries. The spider looks as follows:

```
class BgeSpiderSpider(Spider):
name = 'BGE_Spider'
allowed_domains = ['some site']
start_urls = ['some site']

def parse(self, response):
    l = ItemLoader(item=MySpiderItem(), response=response)
    volumes = response.xpath('some xpath/@href').extract()
    for volume in volumes:
        absolute_volume_url = response.urljoin(volume)
        yield Request(absolute_volume_url, callback=self.parse_volume)

def parse_volume(self, response):
    BGEs = response.xpath('some xpath/@href').extract()
    for BGE in BGEs:
        absolute_BGE_url = response.urljoin(BGE)
        yield Request(absolute_BGE_url, callback=self.parse_BGE)

def parse_BGE(self, response):
    articles = [article.strip() for article in response.xpath('some xpath/text()').extract()]
    articles = list(filter(None, articles))

    considerations = [consideration.strip() for consideration in response.xpath('some xpath/text()').extract()]
    considerations = list(filter(None, considerations))
    merged_considerationsI = [''.join(i) for i in considerations]
    merged_considerationsII = ' '.join(merged_considerationsI)

    facts = [fact.strip() for fact in response.xpath('some xpath/text()').extract()]
    facts = list(filter(None, facts))
    merged_factsI = [''.join(i) for i in facts]
    merged_factsII = ' '.join(merged_factsI)

    items = BGEItem()
    items['articles'] = articles
    items['facts'] = merged_factsII
    items['considerations'] = merged_considerationsII

    yield {
        'Articles': articles,
        'Sachverhalt': merged_factsII,
        'Erwaegungen': merged_considerationsII
    }
```

As said, I now would like to filter out crawled content which is in French language and take such entire dictionaries out of the list (of dictionaries). All the rest of the data is in German. I tried to achieve this as follows (example only for the 'facts' variable):

```
    text = TextBlob(merged_factsII)
    if (text.detect_language() == 'de'):
       merged_facts_german = merged_factsII
```

But this does not work.

'merged_facts_II' should be of data type str; it is actually not a list of Strings. This is why I directly pass it into TextBlob.

I am not sure what the issue is. As said, I am a complete Python newb and hence it may be an absolute trivial problem here.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you considered [polyglot's detector](https://polyglot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Detection.html) to check the language?

Comment: @Treatybreaker not really - but I don't think that this will solve my above issue.

Comment: Not sure if it applies here, but usually the language of the page is specified in the html. You can find it like this:
`language = response.xpath('/html/@lang').extract_first()`

Comment: Thanks @WimHermans - I know, it is specified but only for the page language in general but not the actual content displayed (court decision). Hence, it can still display de (for German) but the decision is still in French.

Comment: Your code block with the language detection seems to run fine on it's own though. can you clarify what the actual problem is when doing it like you described?